# Don't need R, but getting R cannot be resolved to variable error

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm making my first app within eclipse, and I've been watching a YouTube playlist to help along the way (Link below). 
Currently I'm working on building buttons and linking pages to each other. The problem I'm running into is an `R` cannot be resolved to a variable error, for any code like the following.

```
Atlantic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Atlantic);
```

or

```
setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
```

The quick fix wants to import `android.R`. When you do this, the ID kicks off this error "ID" cannot be resolved or is not a field.
The odd thing is, sometimes I can just remove import `android.R` and it will work. However, it tends to come back after adding a picture or something to another screen (that has nothing to do with any Java code (yet) or any ID (yet))

BTW, I don't know if this helps. for the ID I use the `"@+id/bla"` trick.

Comment: *"Don't need R ...."* - yes you do!  It is supposed to be generated ... don't delete it.

Comment: please check your all xml or layout file and clean and remove "import android.R" line in your activity .and clean and run

Comment: That's some bad tutorial you are watching. They should have mentioned the importance of R.java

Comment: Maybe, but they don't have import. In fact, I don't important and I have it running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning your solution and it should regenerate the R.java file.  It basically is a generated file to keep track of all your views/layouts/strings etc.

It is very necessary to make your app work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is fixed now, but that wasn't the solution. However, your answer caused some stuff to happen in the error log and I found the problem. The problem was  1 picture I added was named AB and not ab. Personally, I think the people who makes eclipse should look into that. Like it's the last thing you would think of checking for a common problem.

Comment: @user280655 that is part of understanding naming conventions. The eclipse ide is designed to give you the freedom to do what you need to do while attempting to ensure you following proper protocol, this includes making/learning from your own mistakes

Comment: @user280655 Eclipse is open source,the ADT plugin is the one which would cause such issues.The eclipse that you use is open source and can be used to program in several languages.It is not upto such a multipurpose IDE to check these things.ADT is responsible for the same.Next time take it by default that if you're R file doesnt compile.Its an error with your resources.So check them thoroughly and then clean the project.This is the general procedure if your R file does not generate

Comment: @crua9 Upper case letters aren't allowed in file names. You are limited to a-z, 0-9 and _ (underscore) and . (dot).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

- Clean the project from project->Clean
- Build the project from project->Build

it should show up in blue

Just a little info on what goes under the hood:

When you define something in an xml (like R.id.Atlantic) , there is no way for your JAVA code to know that you defined it. So there is something called your R files that 'bind' the two together.